# JavaScript reset millisecond timer once condition is met?

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to build a very basic countdown timer which counts down from 1 second to 0 and then resets each time in vanilla JS (back to 1 second and counts down). I have the code to get it to run once (1 second down to 0) but am struggling to get it to reset.

Code here:

```
var count = 100; // 1 second
    
var counter = setInterval(timer, 10); //10 will  run it every 100th of a second
    
function timer()
    {
        
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            clearInterval(counter)
            return;
// I think it's something in here I need to add instead of the return call but i'm unsure what? If I add alert boxes etc they do display as I would expect them too. 
        }
        count--;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count /100+ " secs";
    }
```

Anyone know? I'm quite new to JavaScript, so its all a bit of a foreign language currently!

Thanks!

Tried various things such as redeclaring the variables inside the if statement but caused browser crashes?

Just calling the function 'timer();', doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: FYI setTimeout is not accurate.

Comment: So set count back to 100?

Comment: Yup, so it should just repeat the same behaviour it does the first time, hit 0, then go back to 1 and repeat. Trying to avoid doing it as just a pure loop though as I think they aren't that well supported by the community generally in JS?

Comment: So set the `count = 100` and do not clear the interval if you want it to reset back to 100

Comment: I already tried that,  it doesnt work sorry! If you just comment out clearinterval it just stops at 0. You can see it in JSfiddle etc. 

If you do jsfiddle + return (commented out) it just goes down forever rather than resetting at 1.

Comment: Sorry @epascarello, you are right, I'm wrong! 

The following *DOES* work in Jsfiddle... 
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            //clearInterval(counter)
            count = 100;
           return;

Must be an issue withe the platform i'm using, thanks! Have a good evening!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, you can return `setInterval` re-assigned to your variable `counter`

```js
var count = 100; // 1 second
var counter = setInterval(timer, 10); //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

function timer() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        count = 100; // reset count to 100
        return counter = setInterval(timer, 10); // start the timer again
    } else {
        count--;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = count / 100 + " secs";
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="timer">
```

Answer (score 0):

to change as little possible your code (there would be another to do that), I would suggest not to clear the timer, just to reset the variable count.

```js
    let count = 100; // 1 second

    let counter = setInterval(timer, 10); //10 will  run it every 100th of a second

    function timer() {
        if (count <= 0) {
            count = 100;
            return;
// I think it's something in here I need to add instead of the return call but i'm unsure what? If I add alert boxes etc they do display as I would expect them too.
        }
        count--;
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count /100+ " secs";
    }
```

take care now it's running in loop never ending, you have to close the window